# What 80s sci-fi series features a distant planet populated by ancient Egyptians?

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, planets

I am trying to remember a science fiction series from the '80s where humans travel to a distant planet/galaxy using a new kind of fuel source. When they arrive at their destination, they find the planet is already inhabited by Egyptian type people similar to Egypt on Earth.

Comment: Clarify: you mean *ancient Egyptians*? (Like pyramids and pharaohs)?

Comment: A series of **what**? Paperback novels, hardcover books, short stories, radio plays?

Comment: http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LightspeedLeapfrog

Comment: @user26068 I suspect this question is going to get put on-hold for being too broad. Please feel free to edit in additional details (particularly, what type of work you're looking for) and it may get re-opened.

Answer (score 16):

Could you be describing Stargate SG1? It's a bit later than the 1980s (mid-1990s) but it fits the other criteria; interplanetary travel, new fuel source, "ancient egypt in space" concept;

[image]

Answer (score 11):

The combination of 80s and (Space) Egypt made me think of the TV series "[Otherworld](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/Otherworld)"

[image: Othwrworld]

Per Wikipedia;

> "References to Egyptian mythology abound, particularly in the
>   signposts which the Sterlings use to attempt to find Imar; it was
>   implied that the ancient Egyptians either had the ability to travel
>   between universes, or had contact with a people that did."

Comment: The image is too compressed to tell, but is that Greg Brady playing the dad?

Answer (score 7):

It could be the original [Battlestar Galactica](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battlestar_Galactica). Since it aired in the late 70s it is likely you might have seen reruns in the early 80s. From [tvtropes](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PyramidPower)

> The original Battlestar Galactica had the heroes find the lost planet of Kobol. The ancient pyramids on that planet looked suspiciously like the ones in the Giza Plateau.

[image]

After Adama enters the pyramid and finds a journal of the thirteenth colony, it is promptly bombed by Cylon raiders before he can read it.